# Display the Procedure/Function the cursor is in

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe

Does the IDE display the current Procedure or Function that the cursor is inside of? If I search for myVariable is there any way to know (without having to scroll up) which function I landed inside of?

If it is not native are there any plugins that support this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is not available in the IDE itself.

The an open-source [CNPack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t2Zr.png) Wizards have this functionality. See the images below, particularly the highlighted areas of the toolbar and code editor window. (Image from Delphi 2007 IDE, but CNWizards support later versions of Delphi up to and including XE5.)

[image]

It works with code that contains procedural (non-OOP) code as well. Here are two captures of separate procedural functions/procedures, with the relevant portions of the toolbar and code editor highlighted:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll note that recent versions of Norton AV have indicated that     CnPack V1.0.6.705 and V1.0.5.693 are "untrustworthy".

Comment: @BIBD: False positives. I have no issues, and source code is available if you'd rather build it yourself.

Comment: @BIBD - Any antivirus product makes a profit from displaying warnings, so the user "feels" secure. So, the more warnings it shows, the more profit. And because you don't have that many viruses in your computer, it just shows random warnings (aka false positives).

Comment: @KenWhite - so, what is the name of that function in the CnWizards plugin?

Comment: @ServerOverflow: IIRC, it's the Procedures List Wizard.

Comment: Ups. Nope. That's the thing where you press Ctrl+D and a window popup to show all available properties. I need the function, because I work on really shitty code where functions have 2000 lines of code. It is very difficult to figure out in which function you are....

Comment: @ServerOverflow: Then I'm afraid I don't know the name. I'm on vacation, and don't have a computer with Delphi with me.

Answer (score 1):

Castalia has this feature, among other things.

Comment: Castalia is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not an existing IDE functionality, various 3rd party tool providers have added it to their product.

On the list of existing tools is [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html).

On the list of past tools, I'd like to add CodeRush as it was among the first to implement it. [A screenshot can be found here](http://www.ackerson.us/AckersonSoftware/Dev/CodeRush/plugins/CodeSite.html) (scroll down a bit).